# Compact variety which is not projective

Tags: algebraic-geometry

While reading Andreas Gathmann's notes on Algebraic Geometry, I stumbled upon this statement: "Projective varieties form a large class of “compact” varieties that do admit such a unified global description. In fact, the class of projective varieties is so large that it is not easy to construct a variety that is not (an open subset of) a projective variety.".

I know that we can sometimes glue affine varieties together and create compact spaces (in fact, Gathmann constructs $\mathbb{P^1}(\mathbb{C})$ as a compactification of $\mathbb{A}^1$). Also affine varieties are not compact unless they are single points. But my question is: is there an example of a variety which is "compact" but not projective?

Gathman does not provide such an example, so maybe someone here can help.

Comment: Well, I think you first have to find out what Gathmann means by "compact" variety. I am pretty sure he is secretly talking about [complete varieties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_variety).

Comment: @NilsMatthes He is in fact surreptitiously talking about complete varieties. So maybe my question can be paraphrased as: is there a complete variety which is not projective?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I thought you were asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such example does not exist in dimension 1. For dimension 3, see the appendix B in Hartshorne, Example 3.4.1

As Liu pointed out below, there is a list discussing related questions in Hartshorne Chapter II Beneath Remark 4.10.2.

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look at it and see whether I understand it.

Comment: Dear @LiYutong, I remember that Hartshorne mentioned that there is an example of a complex complete singular surface which is not projective in II.4, so your answer has a small mistake.

Comment: Thank you! I have edited the answer.

Comment: There is also an exercise to "construct" one (actually, you merely prove that such a thing must exist as a certain deformation) in Chapter III, but I don't have the book in front of me to give the exact number.